Model loading error Transfer Learning VGG16
enter image description here
Please help to solve this error, I trained the model in jupyter. And I save model as pickle file and load it ang got the prediction on jupyter notebook. But when I tried to load to Flask app, it will give this error.

Welcome to SO; please see how to create a [mre].
